# JavaFX Task ending and JavaFX threading

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I only just started learning about JavaFX today and I was trying to learn more about it by making a Snake clone, but I am having trouble with threading. I wanted to create a thread that updated the snake's position on the screen, but couldn't use one in a normal Runnable thread way, because I was using JavaFX from within that thread to update positions of rectangles drawn to the screen (Which I learned you cannot do, and must instead use Tasks, Services, Platform.runLater, etc?) My class that I was creating the thread from extends JavaFX.scene.layout.Pane, and I am trying to use a task to update the snake position. My problem is: The task only seems to run once or twice and quits, without me giving any interrupts.

Constructor for the class that extends Pane (The Snake class extends Group):

```
public GameFrame(){
    this.setPrefSize(800, 600);

    Snake snake = new Snake();
    this.getChildren().add(snake);

    taskThread = new Thread(new Task<Void>() { 
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    snake.updatePosition();
                    try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch(InterruptedException e){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            return null;
        }
    });
    taskThread.start();
}
```

I feel like I don't actually grasp what the best thing to do here is, and what I am trying to do may be hackish. Are there any suggestions on what I should do, or how I could fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic rules for threading in JavaFX (and forgive me if you already understand some of this, I just want to be complete) are:

1. Anything that blocks execution (or takes a long time to execute) should be run on a background thread - not on the FX Application Thread
2. Anything that changes the state of a `Node` that is part of the scene graph should be executed on the FX Application Thread

In order to help achieve these, the JavaFX API provides a `Task` class. This has a `call()` method that returns a value; it is a `Runnable` so can be provided as the argument to a `Thread` constructor, or passed to an `Executor`. It also provides useful callbacks that are guaranteed to be executed on the FX Application Thread, such as `setOnSucceeded`, `setOnFailed`, and various `update...()` methods that update properties such as `progress` and `message` on the FX Application Thread.

However, the `Task` class is really designed for one-off tasks: think about applications that need to retrieve data from a database, for example, which may take time. These execute a specific action and return a result. Your case is somewhat different, in that your thread is executing continuously.

In this case, it's probably better to use a simple `Thread` and use `Platform.runLater(...)` to update the UI. `Platform.runLater(...)` takes a `Runnable` and executes its `run()` method on the FX Application Thread.

It's not clear to me why your code is behaving the way you describe, but assuming the method call `snake.updatePosition()` causes a change in the UI, that should be executed on the FX Application Thread. In any case I would try

```
taskThread = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        snake.updatePosition();
                    }
                });
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
});
```

If you are using Java 8, this all looks a lot nicer with lambdas replacing the anonymous inner classes:

```
taskThread = new Thread( () -> {
    while (! Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        Platform.runLater( snake::updatePosition );
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            break ;
        }
    }
});
```

One other technique in JavaFX for executing something periodically is to (ab?)use an Animation:

```
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), 
        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                snake.updatePosition();
            }
        }
    ));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
```

or, in Java 8, the somewhat slick

```
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), 
        event -> snake.updatePosition()));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
```