# Running an infinite loop in a JavaFX(Embedded in javax.swing.JFrame) App

Tags: multithreading, javafx-2, infinite-loop, javafx-8

I am trying to run an Infinite loop in my JavaFX app.
An infinite while loop is present in my code in the `Kulta.java` file.
This loop actually freezes my app.
While the same thing works when I port the app to normal javax.swing.
Now since `java.lang.Thread` doesn't work for javafx, I came accross `javafx.concurrent.Task`,
which is not working as intended. As one of the main features of multithreading, i.e. running an infinite loop in a GUI app, is not served properly, please help me with the solution.

This is my code:

**Urania.java**

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;



 public class Urania {

    public static final Dimension DIMENSION = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(

            new Runnable() { 

                @Override
                public void run() {

                     Kulta kulta = new Kulta();
                     kulta.setTitle("Abha K Pauri");
                     kulta.setSize(DIMENSION.width/2, DIMENSION.height/2);
                     kulta.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                     kulta.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                     kulta.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And here is my JFrame in which I have embedded my JavaFX app.

**Kulta.java**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;



public class Kulta extends JFrame {

    private JFXPanel fxpanel;
    private Scene scene;
    private BorderPane borderpane;
    private Button button;



    public static final String INVOKE = "INVOKE";
    public static final String INTERRUPT = "INTERRUPT";
    public static final String[] COLORS = new String[]{"yellow", "pink", "green", "blue", "orange"};



    public Kulta() {

        fxpanel = new JFXPanel();
        add(fxpanel);

        Platform.runLater(

            new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Kulta.this.setScene();
                    Kulta.this.setButton();
                    Kulta.this.setListener();
                } 
            }
        );
    }



    private void setScene() {

        borderpane = new BorderPane();
        scene = new Scene(borderpane);
        fxpanel.setScene(scene);
    }



    private void setButton() {

        button = new Button(INVOKE);
        borderpane.setTop(button);
    }


    private void setListener() {

        Event event = new Event();
        button.setOnAction(event);
    }



    private class Event implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

             boolean flag = true;


             Task<Void> onInvoke = new Task<Void>() {

                 @Override
                 public Void call() {

                     int count = 0;
                     flag = true;
                     button.setText(INTERRUPT);

                     /* This loop freezes the app. */
                     while(flag) {

                         borderpane.setStyle("-fx-color: "+COLORS[count]+";");
                         count++;

                         if(count == COLORS.length)
                             count = 0;
                     }

                     return null;
                 }
             };

             Task<Void> onInterrupt = new Task<Void>() {

                 @Override
                 public Void call() {

                     button.setText(INVOKE);

                     if(flag)
                         flag = false;    // This will stop the onInvoke thread

                     return null;                         
                 }
             };

             Task<Void> change = new Task<Void>() {

                 @Override
                 public Void call() {

                     if(button.getText().equals(INVOKE))
                         onInvoke().run();
                     else if(button.getText().equals(INTERRUPT))
                         onInterrupt().run();
                 }
             };


             change.run();
        }
    }
}
```

How should I write the loop in order to not let the app freeze.
Any code, solution, link or any help in any form will help a lot.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you say "`java.lang.Thread` doesn't work for Javafx"

Comment: @James_D I tried. The code compiles. But at runtime, it says that it is not a JavaFX thread.

Comment: You cannot update the UI from a background thread, but that is true in almost all UI toolkits. See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924414/javafx-task-ending-and-javafx-threading/24924619#24924619